# add the sum of results to an equation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to add the results of ard.terms_amount and subtract that from my "Open AR" calculation. So in this case it should be subtracting 0.90

```
SELECT 
customer.customer_id
,customer.customer_name


,cast(sum(ih.total_amount - ih.amount_paid ) as decimal (10,2)) as [Open A/R]


,cast(dbo.p21_fn_days_sales_outstanding(customer.company_id, customer.customer_id, 90, GETDATE()) as decimal (10,2)) average_dso 
,terms.terms_desc
,ard.terms_amount



FROM customer
INNER JOIN terms ON terms.terms_id = customer.terms_id
inner join invoice_hdr ih on ih.customer_id = customer.customer_id
inner join ar_receipts_detail ard on ard.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE  customer.company_id = 'ABC' and customer.customer_id='123456'
and ih.approved ='y'


group by customer.customer_id,customer.customer_name,customer.company_id,terms.terms_desc,ard.terms_amount
```

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql 2012

Comment: @eggwhites Should `0.9` be subtracted *for each row*, or are you trying to group these into one single row?

Comment: @santi - i updated the pic. there is only one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is take the sum of the column 'terms_amount' and subtract it from the sum of the column 'Open A/R' right?

You can set sum of the columns to two variables then subtract both (please excuse my syntax, for a while I used MSSQL but I recently switched to MySQL for work):

```
declare @terms_amount float; 
declare @OpenA/R float
set @terms_amount = (select sum(terms_amount) from yourdatabase);
set @OpenA/R = (select sum(OpenA/R) from yourdatabase);
select @terms - @OpenA/R;
```

I think the syntax is correct, but again, I haven't used MSSQL in a while.